# Hibernate Print Before and After Update

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have this little issue I'm struggling with. I have a very similar Update query. What I want is to see the result before and after the Update. The update is done successfully but there is some issue in the printing. I believe there is some small thing I'm missing.

The code:

```
EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("exercise");
EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String address = scanner.nextLine();
String lastName = scanner.nextLine();

Employee employee = findEmployee(entityManager, lastName);
printEmployeeData(employee); // Prints Employee data before the Update

entityManager.createQuery(
                "UPDATE Employee e" +
                        " SET e.address = :address" +
                        " WHERE e.lastName = :name")
        .setParameter("address", address)
        .setParameter("name", lastName)
        .executeUpdate(); // Successfully updated the Employee

System.out.printf("%n%n");
employee = findEmployee(entityManager, lastName);
printEmployeeData(employee); // Prints the same output as the one before the Update

entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
entityManager.close();


private static Employee findEmployee(EntityManager entityManager, String lastName) {
    return entityManager.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Employee e" +
                    " WHERE lastName = :lastName", Employee.class)
            .setParameter("lastName", lastName)
            .getSingleResult();
}
```

I think the problem might be somewhere in the entityManager?

Comment: Try by moving `employee = findEmployee(entityManager, lastName);
printEmployeeData(employee);` after `entityManager.getTransaction().commit();`. I am guessing the changes are not committed before you fetch it.

Comment: Tried it, but the result was the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `entityManager.refresh(employee)` to fetch the results of the `UPDATE` query from the database.

The entity manager has no way to know which entities in memory were affected by the `UPDATE`.